# Providing data for Bulk 2.0 API Salesforce from a CSV file

Tags: salesforce

I've been looking at the Bulk 2.0 API for SalesForce for uploading data. All the examples say that in the request body I need to provide the contents of the CSV file. Below is from official salesforce docs:

`Request Body:
(Content of your CSV file)`

I'd like to know if there is a way to just provide a link/path to the file?

Answer (score 0):

The `BulkConnection` class provides several methods that provide the ability to pass the batch as a stream, notably `createBatchFromStream`.